# IN Logout Link How TO Redirect the user to same area where user previous in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

after log out I want The User To redirect to the same area How Can I Do that
Here Is My Code

```
<pre>
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">
      <button type="submit" style="width: auto"  class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                                    Logout @User.Identity.Name
      </button>
 </form>
</pre>
 public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
 {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
 }
```

I want The User To Go Back To Same Area Home Page I am Using Same Account Controller In all Region

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, in your project:

•   The logout form is located in the layout template which will be rendered for all pages

•   The logout method is constructed in the Account controller which is in the root level.

•   The requirement is that whenever you click the logout button, you will be redirect to the index page of the current area. For example, log out in '/Product/Home/Details', the user should be redirected to '/Product/Home/index', where the 'Product' is the area.

With the given information, I suggest you store the area value in the hidden field of the logout form. Then this area value will be passed to the logout method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

logout form:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" asp-area=""> 
            <button type="submit" style="width: auto" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                Logout @User.Identity.Name
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="area" value="@ViewContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["area"]" />
        </form>
```

Logout action (in AccountController):

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string area) 
        {

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home", new { area = area });
        }
```

/Home/Index View:

```
@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 >Root Index Page</h1>
    
</div>

<a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="Product"> Move to /Product/Home/Details page</a>
```

/Product/Home/Index View:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; ;
}
<h1> Product Area/ Home / Index View</h1>
```

/Product/Home/Details View:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; ;
}
<h1> Product Area/ Home / Details View</h1>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: i have send you connection link for linkin-in jsut stay in touch if i need something leave you message

Comment: that work but now come up with new question in Login Link it in Root Path so value value="@ViewContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["area"]"  is null and end up with tdispaly root home Idex page after successfull login

Comment: in your demo did you see after login it back too root index page i want the page to stay area index

Comment: Could you please edit the problem and post the related codes?
I understand the problem that you have but I have no idea how you implement the login link with the area.
Thank you for understanding.

Comment: the same thing in your demo

Comment: Since I don't know your login in codes, I suggest you could start a new SO thread to talk about the issue which is related with login in Notice: Please post related login codes.  This case is mainly talking about the logout question. If you feel the login out question has been solved. Please mark it as answer and start a new thread , so that other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily. Thank you.

Comment: I know but this is the logout codes. I need your login codes. We need to pass the current url when called login controller method and then redirect to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659794/how-to-redirect-to-same-area-where-login-happen-after-successfully-login